# is this possible to calculate the resize image size within actually resize it?

Tags: image, resize

Let say, I can read an image, and resize it to the size I want. But I would like to do something tricky. I got a image size 5MB, but I would like to resize it in not larger than 512KB. is this possible to calculate how much do I need to resize? Or it can just simply calculated by org size diverted by prefer size? thanks.

*You can use whatever language you want to implement it.

Comment: Just a thought, for image file saving, it may involve compression (such as JPEG), which can add complexity when calculating the size. Perhaps one thought is to do something like binary search algorithm, with the thing to be searched is the filesize which is 512KB, so you will try resizing those images multiple times (you may want to preserve the aspect ratio), and in the end comes up with the desired filesize. It may be a bit time consuming, but perhaps you can give it a try.

Comment: I think @rcs is right, you have to continually resize the image until you reach near the file size 512 kb because file size depends upon the resolution (pixel/inch) of the image and is differ for different extension.

Comment: @rcs let make the question clear...if the org image is 5120KB, even involve compression, if I just diverted the org size to (org image/prefer image), the result should become equal to 512KB or less, right? Would it have a chance to become more than 512KB? Thanks.

Comment: @TedWong. As I have mentioned, the compression can play a lot in the image size. I just made some experiment, I have a `5,184*3,456=17,915,904 pixels` with size of `8,142,928 bytes`. When I resize it to `1,639*1,093=1,791,427 pixels` which is `1/10` of the original size, the filesize is `1,457,977 bytes`, which is around 5 times smaller. The resizing and saving is done with Paint.NET, JPEG quality of 100. So you can see the image file size does not really conform with the ratio of the image resized. and if you play around with the JPEG quality, you will get varying result as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no compression then it is simple as you mention; otherwise it depends on the subject...

This algorithm would work:

1. Calculate the scale factor to reduce the current image pixel dimensions to half size
2. Scale the image to half size
3. Calculate the file size. If file size too big GOTO step 1 otherwise the scale factor you calculated in step one is your answer.

Comment: here you have to also check that file size will not exact 512 kb.. may be 500 kb  or 510 kb or 525 kb ...

Comment: Sure, it could even be 0KB :) To make it better, once you find the answer you could do the reverse algorithm scaling up a quarter size until you exceed 512 KB.